How to get the result of a goal execution on a different machine?
I am using this tool which exposes a server to speech to text service:
https://github.com/MERLIN2-ARCH/speech_to_text
The command to send a goal is:
$ ros2 action send_goal /speech_to_text/listen_once speech_to_text_msgs/action/ListenOnce {}

I suppose this will trigger the tool to turn vocal speech to text in the console.
But how to get the text in an action client subscriber
(https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Writing-an-Action-Server-Client/Py.html)
that runs on a different connected machine?
Thanks
